# open and closed and bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis

people

> interval $[0,1]$, is closed interval
>
> can you say such interval $[0,1]$ is bounded or not??
>
> if it is how to show this interval is bounded ?(proof?)
>
> or interval is not enough to say this is bounded or not
>
> is only apply to the function $f()$?

thank you

Comment: What is your definition of bounded? If you understand the definition it should be pretty clear that $[0,1]$ is bounded. Can you find a ball of finite radius about $0$ such that $[0,1]$ is completely contained in it?

Answer (score 3):

The interval $[0,1]=\{\,x\in\mathbb R\mid 0\le x\le 1\,\}$ is bounded because we can explicitly exhibit a bound for the absolute value of its elements. For example $42$ is such a bound as $0\le x\le 1$ is eaily shown to imply $|x|\le 42$.

Answer (score 2):

$[0,1]$ is bounded in $\mathbb R$ because there is a point $0$ in $\mathbb R$ from which the distance to any point in this interval is bounded by $1$.